# python sorting a dictionary based on values, and order based on key if values are repeating

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How to sort a dictionary in two dimensions efficiently
 The dictionary is something like this i need to rank each key based on its values key with highest value gets minimum rank. If 2 keys have same value then they are ordered in lexicographical order  :

```
d = {'T': 1500, 'L': 1000, 'P': 1500, 'G': 6500, 'B': 7000}
```

expected output :

```
1 :  B
2 :  G
3 :  P
3 :  T
4 :  L
```

Here since the values of T and P are repeated they are to be sorted in alphabetical order

Comment: Expected output of *what*? Anyway, you can't sort dictionaries. You need a different data structure.

Comment: It appears you want to sort the keys of a dict by their values; is that correct? It might be good to read through the [Python sorting howto](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Comment: Is it required that P and T (since they have the same value) have the same rank? Or would rank 3 and 4 be suitable, provided those are in lexicographical order.

Comment: they need to have same rank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sort by key, and then by descending value:

```
>>> d = {'T': 1500, 'L': 1000, 'P': 1500, 'G': 6500, 'B': 7000}
>>> sorted(sorted(d), key=d.get, reverse=True)
['B', 'G', 'P', 'T', 'L']
```

The second sort doesn't change the previously-sorted order of entries that have equal values.

You can also use a `tuple` to sort by more than one key:

```
>>> d = {'T': 1500, 'L': 1000, 'P': 1500, 'G': 6500, 'B': 7000}
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: (-d.get(x), x))
['B', 'G', 'P', 'T', 'L']
```

To assign the same "rank" to keys that have the same value: save the sorted `list` of keys, initialize `rank`, `value`, and `ranks` references, and iterate through the keys. For each key, the `rank` is increased if the previous `value` is different from this key's value. Since `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` is equivalent to `0`, we can simply add the result of this comparison directly to the `rank`. We then save the current key's `value` for comparison with the next one. Finally, add this to the `ranks` dictionary with `key` as the key and `rank` as the value.

```
>>> value = 0
>>> rank = 0
>>> ranks = {}
>>> for key in s:
...     rank += value != d[key]
...     value = d[key]
...     ranks[key] = rank
...
```

Now it's easy to iterate through this dictionary and print the results you were looking for:

```
>>> for k in s:
...     print('{}: {}'.format(ranks[k], k))
...
1: B
2: G
3: P
3: T
4: L
```

Comment: @prime130392 - I've added a way to determine and save the rank of each key.